# Excelhow to use formula find the specific text to count according a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to check if there is any formula can be apply this kind of condition to get the expected count result as per highlighted

I have Hotel Code a list and how can I write a formula to find from column P whether there is any text match with the hotel code then count

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND("|"&AD2&"|","|"&P$2:P$14&"|")))`
Wrap the lookup word in `|`'s and make sure the search column starts and ends with `|`, then sum the number of rows where it finds the lookup word.

Comment: Thanks for advise and it seems work for this formula. But I have one concern since the Column P is a free text box, if there is a condition text like below that agent did not follow the standard format "|" then the formula will not able to count which below example have involve SLP & GSH hotel but did not follow using "|". So, I would like to seek for your advise if there is any way to fit this kind of condition as well? 

SLP - room booking 

GSH F&B

Comment: I wouldn't advise using `=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(AD2,P$2:P$14)))` since if a longer name consists a shorter letter combination it will return false positives. Why change the standard for somebody not following it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following formula, which spills using the `LAMBDA()` helper function `BYROW()` all at once.

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(AD2:AD10,LAMBDA(x,COUNT(FIND("|"&x&"|","|"&P2:P14&"|"))))
```

---

Comment: This formula seems work, but I have one concern since the Column P is a free text box, if there is a condition text like below that agent did not follow the standard format | then the formula will not able to count which below example have involve SLP & GSH hotel but did not follow using |.

So, I would like to seek for your advise if there is any way to fit this kind of condition as well?

SLP - room booking

GSH F&B

Comment: Whatever issue you have that should be updated in the post and also the update should be in the original post from very beginning, not likely after when members have already posted some solution based on OP.